# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;heck the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php

the below is my query and when i run in db its shows error like #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

```
  INSERT INTO`expense`(Request,Date,Employee,Load,Truck,Amount,Purpose,Mode,Remark) 
     VALUES ('$Request','$Date','$Employee','$Load','$Truck','$Amount','$Purpose','$Mode','$Remark')
```

Can sumbdy help!!

Comment: Usually the error message also specifies *where* the syntax error occurs.  Are you sure that's the complete error message?

Comment: Add the full error message.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Load,Truck,Amount,Purpose,Mode,Remark) VALUES ('2323','53553','hfhfh','5464' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Date** & **Load** are the reserved keywords. Use back ticks -

```
INSERT INTO `expense` (`Request`,`Date`,`Employee`,`Load`,`Truck`,`Amount`,`Purpose`,`Mode`,`Remark`) 
 VALUES ('$Request','$Date','$Employee','$Load','$Truck','$Amount','$Purpose','$Mode','$Remark')
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mysqli_real_escape_string` might be some problem with variable containing string's

```
$Request = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $Request);   

INSERT INTO `expense`(`Request`,`Date`,`Employee`,`Load`,`Truck`,`Amount`,`Purpose`,`Mode`,`Remark`) 
         VALUES ('".$Request."',............)
```

Comment: <?php
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) $Request=$_POST['Request'] ;
     $Date= $_POST['Date'] ;     
     $Employee=$_POST['Employee'] ;
     $Load=$_POST['Load'] ;
     $Truck=$_POST['Truck'] ;
     $Amount=$_POST['Amount'] ;
     $Purpose=$_POST['Purpose'] ;
     $Mode=$_POST['Mode'] ;
     $Remark=$_POST['Remark'] ;
$query =  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `expense` (Request,Date,Employee,Load,Truck,Amount,Purpose,Mode,Remark VALUES ('$Request','$Date','$Employee','$Load','$Truck','$Amount','$Purpose','$Mode','$Remark')"); }?>

Comment: @User have you tried above code and is there any error